# How to replace $x$ and $x^2$ with different value?

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching, distributions, expression-manipulation

I have an expression now

```
expr = x + x^2
```

what I want to do is to replace $x$ with $k\times p$ , and $x^2$ with $[k\times p + k\times(k - 1)\times p^2]$.

The sense of this opperation is that $x$ is a binomial random variable, and I want to take expection of the expression above, so I make the substituation.
However, when I try to make the first substitution

```
expr = ReplaceAll[expr, x -> k*p]
```

I obtain the following output

```
kp + k^2 p^2
```

which is not what I want. So my question is what can I do to obtain the right answer?

I am new to Mathematica, so my question may seem a little bit silly. But I am still appreciate if someone could help me with that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Give the replacement rules in a list:

```
expr /. {x^2 -> k p + k (k - 1) p^2, x -> k p}
```

> 2 k p + (-1 + k) k p^2

Comment: That's a good way! by the way I also tried to exchange the order expr /. {x -> k p, x^2 -> k p + k (k - 1) p^2}, and it also works!

Comment: @Yuejiang_Li, thank you for the accept. You are right; the rules can appear  in either order in this case.

Answer (score 6):

If you are calculating the expectation of an expression, use [`Expectation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Expectation.html) or other built-in statistics functions rather than replacements which can be error-prone (which is why you ended up asking the question).

```
expr = x + x^2;

Expectation[expr, x \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[k, p]] //
 Simplify

(* k p (2 + (-1 + k) p) *)
```

Alternatively, using [`TransformedDistribution`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TransformedDistribution.html) and [`Mean`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mean.html)

```
Mean[TransformedDistribution[expr, 
   x \[Distributed] BinomialDistribution[k, p]]] // Simplify

(* k p (2 + (-1 + k) p) *)
```

Verifying that both results are identical,

```
% === %%

(* True *)
```

Comment: @Hanlon Thanks for your answer! I didn't realize mathematica can use expectation directly. But what if I only know different moments of $X$, rather than its distribution? will this method still work?

Comment: @Yuejiang_Li - You need the distribution to use `Expectation` or `TransformedDistribution`. If you know **all** of the moments, then you can derive the distribution from the moments. Or, if you know the general form of the distribution, you can determine or estimate the distribution from a few of the moments. Questions about statistics should be asked at [`Cross Validated`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 2):

This is entirely equivalent to Bob's answer:

```
x + x^2 /. x^m_. :> Moment[BinomialDistribution[k, p], m]
   2 k p - (1 - k) k p^2
```